# Classifying Group of Order 26 up to Isomorphism

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Classify all groups of order 26.

I know that the answer should be the dihedral group of order 13, as well as $Z13XZ2$; however, I'm not sure a good way to show that the dihedral group should be included as well using Sylow theorems without using the semi direct product. Any suggestions?

Comment: Any subgroup of index 2 must be normal, so your $13$-Sylow must be normal. Therefore the group must be some kind of semidirect product of $Z_{13}$ and $Z_2$.

Comment: Thank you! I was actually wondering if there was a way to show without using semi direct product, since we have not covered it in class yet. I've edited the question to reflect this.

Comment: Yes, if your copy of $Z_2$ is $\{1,a\}$, you just need to check what $axa^{-1}$ must be (in various cases) for each element $x$ of your $13$-Sylow. That way, you can obtain a complete description of the group.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $G$ be a group of order $26=2\cdot13$.

If $G$ is abelian, then by the fundamental theorem of finitely generated abelian group. $G\cong \Bbb{Z}_2\times \Bbb{Z}_{13}\cong \Bbb{Z}_{26}$.

Suppose now $G$ is non-abelian. By Cauchy's Theorem, there is a subgroup $H$ of order $13$ and a subgroup $K$ of order $2$. Clearly, $H$ and $K$ are cyclic. Write $H=\langle h\rangle$ and $K=\langle k \rangle$. Since $H$ is of index $2$ in $G$, $H$ is a normal subgroup of $G$. Hence $HK\leq G$. Since $(|H|,|K|)=1$, by product formula, $|G|=|HK|$, so that $G=HK$.

Note that $khk^{-1}\in H$. Hence $khk^{-1}=h^i$ for some $i$. Then $h=k^2hk^{-2}=h^{i^2}$. Hence $i^2\equiv 1\bmod 13$, which means that $i\equiv \pm1 \bmod 13$. Since $G$ is non-abelian, we can only have $khk^{-1}=h^{-1}$. Therefore $G$ is a dihedral group of order $26$.

General case:

> If $G$ is a group of order $2p$ where $p$ is a prime, then $G$ is either cyclic or dihedral.